# VBA - Multiline Textbox to SQL IN statement

Tags: vba, excel

As the title states, I have a multiline textbox that I need to copy/paste multiple values into ( that'd exist on each line ) and have them turn into an array, which would build an SQL In statement. I'm already doing this with a listbox that works perfect, but can't figure out doing it with a textbox

My textbox is named form_payment_inv with multiline enabled.

Example of a copy/paste

```html
1234
5678
```

Desired output would be

```html
IN ('1234','5678')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Split the text box's multiple lines by \r\n
    Dim myarr() As String
    myarr() = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf)

    ' Find total items contained in the array and put single quotes around them
    Dim TotalItems As Integer
    TotalItems = UBound(myarr)        
    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 0 To TotalItems
        myarr(I) = "'" & myarr(I) & "'"
    Next I

    ' create the IN statement
    Dim SQL_IN As String
    SQL_IN = Join(myarr, ",")
    MsgBox SQL_IN
End Sub
```

The result will be `'1234','5678'`

Comment: I'm getting "Expected Array" on TotalItems = UBound(myarr)